# Trouble with the integral of an infinitely differentiable function with compact support

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I'm really triggered by not finding the mistake in the following lines.

Suppose $f \in C^\infty_0$ ($C_0$ stands for a function with compact support). Then,

$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f'(x) = [f(x)]^{+\infty}_{-\infty} $ = 0.

I sense that my anti-derivative is wrong, but I can't explain to myself why. Thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you don't understand?

Comment: By the fundamental theorem of calculus $f'$ needs only be continuous for the statement to hold.

Comment: I thought actually thought that an even function as Jean Marie showed below was a counter-example. Turns out it's not. So I guess there's no mistake? What is the intuition behind this integral being equal to zero ? And what would have happened if I was looking at the integral of the absolute value of the derivative ?

Comment: The integral of the absolute value of $|f'(t)|$ which is $\ge0$ isn't equal to zero in general because if you integrate a positive valued function, you cannot get zero unless it is identically zero. But the fundamental theorem of analysis doesn't say that $f(t)$ is a primitive function of $|f'(t)|$.

Answer (score 2):

No mistake.

Look at the following graphics representing the case of an even function $f$ (red) ; its derivative (blue) will be odd and the positive and the negative area parts will compensate each other :

[image]